# How to call python2.5 function from x86asm/x64asm?

Tags: python, assembly

I'll have couple of python functions I must interface with from the assembly code. The solution doesn't need to be a complete solution because I'm not going to interface with python code for too long. Anyway, I chewed it a bit:

- What does a python object look like in memory?
- How can I call a python function?
- How can I pass python objects as python objects for ctypes interface?
- Could ctypes interface make my work easier in any alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to read and understand [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://python.org/doc/2.5/ext/ext.html) and the [Python/C API Reference Manual](http://python.org/doc/2.5/api/api.html). This describes how to interface with Python from C. Everything you can do in C you can equivalently do in assembly code too, but you're on your own for this as it is not directly described from a Python perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly doable, but you'd have a much easier time reading the C API docs and writing a go-between function in C.

Come to think of it, C is highly recommended, since it may be hard to tell which of the routines you're calling might be implemented as preprocessor macros.